# C# BaseStream returning same MD5 hash regardless of what is in the stream

Tags: c#, .net, hash, stream, md5

The question says it all.  This code

```
string hash = "";
using (var md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create())  
{  
    hash = Convert.ToBase64String(md5.ComputeHash(streamReader.BaseStream));  
}
```

will always return the same hash.

If I pass all of the data from the BaseStream into a MemoryStream, it gives a unique hash every time.  The same goes for running

```
string hash = "";  
using (var md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create())  
{  
    hash = Convert.ToBase64String(md5.ComputeHash(
              Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(streamReader.ReadToEnd())));  
}
```

The second one is actually faster, but I've heard it's bad practice.

My question is, what is the proper way to use ComputeHash(stream).  For me it always (and I mean always, even if I restart the program, meaning it's not just hashing the reference) returns the same hash, regardless of the data in the stream.

Comment: The `Stream` instance is likely positioned at the end of the stream. `ComputeHash` returns the hash for the bytes from the current position to the end of the stream. So if the current position *is* the end of the stream, it will the hash for the empty input. Make sure that the `Stream` instance is positioned at the beginning of the stream. And note that it's bad practice to access the `BaseStream` of a `StreamReader`.

Comment: This was the problem! I wish you posted it as an answer, rather than a comment so I could pick yours though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `Stream` instance is likely positioned at the end of the stream. `ComputeHash` returns the hash for the bytes from the current position to the end of the stream. So if the current position is the end of the stream, it will the hash for the empty input. Make sure that the `Stream` instance is positioned at the beginning of the stream.

Comment: Thank you so much - for significantly reducing the amount of time I spent before I finally facepalmed.

Comment: This is scary, i had this mistake to.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue by setting *stream.Position = 0* before *ComputeHash*